# Exclude folder in Sublime SFTP and skip scanning

Tags: sftp, sublimetext, yeoman, sublimetext3

I am using yeoman to scaffold an angular project. In this folder there is a folder called node_modules. I excluded the folder in the ignore regexes. But it seems Sublime SFTP still scans through it.

What I want to do is exclude the folder even for scanning. It takes like an hour before it's done scanning.

```
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini", "/var/www/webapp/node_modules/"
```

Comment: The issue seems to be that SFTP lists the contents of all folders before deciding which ones to download / sync.  This is really a feature request to change the behavior on syncing to not list the contents of folders matching the ignore list.

Comment: 5 years later, i think this problems still not solved it. SFTP plugin is v1.14.1. Any update on this?